# How to downgrade SSIS package created in VS 2015 to VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, visual-studio-2015

How do I convert/downgrade a SSIS package (.dtsx file) that I created in VS 2015 to work with VS 2010? Is there a way I can force this action by changing the .sln settings in notepad? or maybe another work around. I have spent hours on creating packages in VS 2015 and the client is not able to upgrade to 2015 anymore. Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Update: Tried changing the connector to 10.1 - came back with this error:

[image]

Trying to make it work on version 2010 shown below:

[image]

Post making version change from 8 to 6:

[image]

Comment: Open the dtsx package with notepad...download the SQLNCI connector to the right version...save the file...create an SSIS project with VS 2010, add the existing package...the conversion should be automatic....

Comment: I am on the server which has VS 2010 installed so I guess I dont need to download a SQLNCI connector.. right? Once I open the dtsx package in notepad - do I need to change anything in it?

Comment: Yeah...the connector version...find and replace the version `11.1` to `10.1`

Comment: I tried what you suggested and got an error. Updated the original question with the screenshot.. what else do you think I need to change? Seems like it doesnt like the package version format '8'

Comment: I changed it from 8 to 6 and got a few errors but after I pressed OK - it still shows me all the data flows that I had. I guess I just need to update the data connections again. Will update if it works! thanks!!

Comment: So i tried updating the connections but noticed that my execute SQL tasks were giving me errors (added a new screenshot above.. please let me know if there is a way I can fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015, open your SSIS project (MyProject.dtproj). You can then go into the Properties Menu and within those menus there, you can specify the version of SQL Server this project should target (2012/2014/2016).

Comment: Worked beautifully. I just followed what you said and didnt even have to make updates to the dtsx file in notepad. Thanks!