# How to find version of installed SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

It is local machine without an actual SQL server (just used for development)

By running DTEXEC it retreived 
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.50.1600.1 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.

SQL server 2008R2 is installed with SDK, SSIS, and management studio

Visual studio 2013 is installed but due to some unknown reason SSDT did not provide full features to SSIS (included .dtsx cannot open and .sqlproj cannot open)

No choice but installed a package called SSDTBI for visual studio 2013. Ridiculously only 32 bit application can be installed(my os is 64bit) and it forces SQL server 2014 installed.

However, visual studio 2013 can open .dtsx & .sqlproj

Everything looks fine (ignoring now this local instance contains SQL server 2008R2, 2012 and 2014 from 2008R2 discs, visual studio 2013 & SSDTBI https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313)

Lastly, when I open the .dtsx file (which should be 2008R2 version)

The program will modify the format the XML to other format 
from

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">3</DTS:Property>
```

to

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
```

It is checked means the SSIS package is in SQL server 2014 now.

Thus the questions are
How exactly to check the current SSIS version (not SSIS package or SQL server or SSDT)

(Skipped) Is it possible to open SSIS items without the encountered issues? 
- it is checked that visual studio 2013 is proposed to manage SSIS package with version 8. Thus it is normal behaviors instead of issue (editing SSIS package version 3 should use visual studio 2008 with BI instead)

[image]

Comment: The SSIS version you have directly relates to the data engine version. SQL Server 2008R2 has SSIS 2008R2. SQL Server 2014 has SSIS 2014. If, however, you have a SQL Server 2008(r2) instance you have to use BIDS in VS 2008. SSDT supports SSIS 2012+, it does not support 2008.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Integration Services Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128727/sql-server-integration-services-version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Thus the questions are How exactly to check the current SSIS version
>   (not SSIS package or SQL server or SSDT)

One server can have multiple versions of SSIS installed. This can be caused by in-place upgrades.

Installed **Major** versions can be discovered by using **SQL Server Configuration Manager**:

[image]

Builds, versions and tools requirements:

```
SQL      Build#  PackageFormatVersion   Visual Studio Version(SSDT)
2005       9        2                   2005
2008      10        3                   2008
2008 R2   10.5      3                   2008
2012      11        6                   2010 or BI 2012
2014      12        8                   2012 CTP2 or 2013
2016      13        8                   2015
2017      14        8                   2015/2017
```

> Is it possible to open SSIS items without the encountered issues?

By default, BIDS creates a backup of package during upgrade

Comment: there is only one application SQL server 2014 configuration manager. I opened it and nothing is shown under the SQL server services

Comment: Then you have got answer to your primary question - you have no SSIS service installed on a workstation. The binaries like  BIDS or SSDT have own integrated SSIS environment and opening your package in newer version of IDE will perform an implicit upgrade of it

Comment: out of curious, i am not sure if it is correct or not

Comment: you said i didn't install SSIS

Comment: but i can run an application which reading an SSIS package (the SSIS package is connecting to external database, they properly contain SSIS, but i dont think it is relevant)

Comment: the point is no SSIS installed in the instance, and able to execute an application which is reading SSIS package and do things

Comment: In SSMS, right click on any user database then task->Import Data..", this will open a wizard which **will generate and execute SSIS package** under the hood to import data.  This example shows that a presense of SSIS service is not necessary to execute packages, because installation of SSMS does not trigger installation of SSIS. In fact, SSIS service acts like a "catalog" and execution runtime for existing packages. But execution of the packages can be also embedded in other apps. SSMS, BIDS are such examples.