# SSIS:Builds and Run Successfully in VS2017 but in server Failed to compiled scripts contained in the package. it seems like sintaxis is wrong but isnt

Tags: c#, ssis, compiled

My SSIS project builds and run succesfully in VS2017. But when I copy the dtsx file into my server and use cmd to run it, I get error this error:

Error Log in CMD

[image: Error Log in CMD]

Basically, I'm using Script Task to invoke api rest with C#. The error is like the sintaxis were wrong but it run successfully in visual studio.

This is the list of program the server has. Do I need something else in the server?

Server's Program and Features

[image: Server's Program and Features]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647526/how-to-find-version-of-installed-ssis

Comment: i executed the same batch in my laptop (VS installed) and I have the same error. do you know why?

Comment: As it doesn't execute fine on your laptop as well, you propably have not enquoted or escaped all parameters you process, try printing the commands in question.

Comment: The first things I would check, make sure you have the same version of SQL installed in both environments (or that the package is built for the correct SQL version where you are deploying it) and verify you actually have SSIS installed on the server/system you are running the package.

Comment: I always run my SSIS packages in my laptop through batch file with no problem. But in this case my package have Script task with C#. It runs fine without the script task. I have no parameters in the batch file I have all in the database in a table.

Comment: Hm, ok. So the error messages talk about lines 145 and 150 of ScriptMain.cs. I'd bet somethings is evaluated in there that contains characters not being escaped. As you shared no source code, we ave to guess though.

Comment: Yes, it was the code. In VS there is no problem with **Res.Estado is null**, builds and runs fine. But in cmd show error. So I erase this part and just left **Res.Estado == string.Empty** and everything is fine now.

                `if (Res.Estado is null || Res.Estado == string.Empty)
                {
                    Dts.Variables["v_EstadoAdd"].Value = "ERROR DESCONOCIDO";
                    Dts.Variables["v_MensajeAdd"].Value = response.StatusCode.ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase.ToString(); 
                }`