# Find Version of Visual Studio Tools for Application in use by SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a client who has Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015, 2017 and 2019 installed. They are in the process of moving to a new server and need to identify what version the SSIS packages (that are deployed to the SQL Server) are using. How do I get that information?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647731/10376537

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for the reply, but no, it doesn't help. I'm referring to the Visual Studio Tools for Application version. This is not the same as SSIS.

Comment: are you talking about which version of VS should you use for the future deployment? or just the package version?